CodeGPT (2.14.1-241.1) plugin is not working with pycharm-community-2024.3
CodeGPT (CodeGPT-2.14.1-241.1.zip) plugin is not working with pycharm-community-2024.3 also tried with pycharm-community-2024.1.7.
I want to install codegpt plugin in above pycharm versions in docker container so I tried to download codegpt zip file and unzipped in /opt/pycharm-community-2024.3/plugins and opened pycharm it does not show codegpt plugin in the right navigation bar  , same I did it with old version of pycharm pycharm-community-2022.3.2 and CodeGPT-2.9.0-223.zip and it was working and I wanted upgrade with latest version but it is not working
I also tried with cli and it says it is installed in terminal then opened pycharm but could not see codegpt in right navigation
./pycharm.sh installPlugins ee.carlrobert.chatgpt
Reference links:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/21056-codegpt
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/other.html
Note :If we install codegpt plugin from Pycharm settings gui it is working but I want to install it during image creation hence I have either download zip file or install it with cli but both are not working with above mentioned latest versions, please help here to achieve this and also is it a bug in new versions or any other way to achieve it
